# MySQL Multiple COUNT in the same table in a single request

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with my SQL request. I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phonenumber` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `avinumber` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `source` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `nbrtryies` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `treaty_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'KO',
  `campagne_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `treated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nodetree_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avi` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sessionid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_contact_campagne1_idx` (`campagne_id`),
  KEY `fk_contact_agent1_idx` (`treated_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_agent` FOREIGN KEY (`treated_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_contact_campagne1` FOREIGN KEY (`campagne_id`) REFERENCES `campagne` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=82 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to count the number of the rows and the number of the rows when the column:

```
treated_by
```

has a certain value and group the result by that column

Thsi is what I did but I doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT 
    co.treated_by AS userId,
    COUNT(*) AS treated,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ca.userId=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM
    contact AS co
        INNER JOIN
    campagne AS ca ON ca.id = co.campagne_id
WHERE
    (co.date BETWEEN '2013-07-09' AND '2014-08-15')
        AND co.treated_by IN (2 , 40)
GROUP BY co.treated_by
```

This is what I got:

```
----------------------------
| userId | treated | total |
----------------------------
|    2   |    5    |   5   |
----------------------------
|   40   |    3    |   3   |
----------------------------
```

And I need something like:

```
----------------------------
| userId | treated | total |
----------------------------
|    2   |    5    |   20  |
----------------------------
|   40   |    3    |   20  |
----------------------------
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY co.treated_by  , It produces record   COUNT(*) AS treated 5 and 3 , so   SUM(CASE WHEN ca.userId=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total  , It is impossible much than 20 and 20.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by impossible?
Can I get the result in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is on `co.treated_by`, then why does the logic contain `ca.userId`?

Perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT co.treated_by AS userId,
       COUNT(*) AS treated,
       SUM(co.treated_by) AS total
FROM contact co INNER JOIN
     campagne ca
     ON ca.id = co.campagne_id
WHERE (co.date BETWEEN '2013-07-09' AND '2014-08-15') AND
      co.treated_by IN (2 , 40)
GROUP BY co.treated_by;
```

Note that I also replaced the calculation for `total` with a simpler version supported by MySQL.